# Self signed certificate SSL Error using self hosted GitLab

Tags: ssl, https, gitlab

I have a hosted Git repo on my company intranet. I can clone, pull, push, etc successfully with command line Git by disabling sslverify. I know this is not ideal but I have no control over our certificate or IT infrastructure so it is what it is.

I paid for GitLab EE, setup the omnibus package and I'm trying to clone the repo via https. However I get an error that it cannot verify the SSL certificate. This is not entirely unexpected but I cannot figure out how to bypass the ssl verification with GitLab EE. In the http settings I set self verified to true and pointed it to my .pem in /etc/gitlab/ssl but I get the same error.

Can I just set sslverify to false like I did command line git?

Comment: Are you trying to clone with git or are you using a external program which issues git commands?

Comment: GitLab apparently runs its own clone command that does not use the native Git.

Comment: Wait. Are you trying to clone **TO** GitLab or **FROM** GitLab?

Comment: I have a Git repo hosted on the internal Git server. I'm trying to use GitLab as an interface for my team to manage issues and CI, etc. I stood up the Git repo with a Readme.txt and now I'm trying to point GitLab to is. I don't care about the clone at all. However in GitLab when I say create new project it asks where I am hosting the project. I say a self hosted Git and it asks for the link. I put in the link and GitLab issues a clone command.

Comment: @lazy8s Is your problem solved ? Feel free to accept the best answer to close topic thks

Answer (score 2):

Since GitLab fails to pull from a Repo because the certificate check failed, you can set git specific settings in your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. There is a key called `omnibus_gitconfig['system']` there your config should be something like:

```
omnibus_gitconfig['system'] = { "http" => ["sslVerify = false"]}
```

**This is bad practice and you should use it with caution.**

You could specify the domain to disable certificate checks for with:

```
omnibus_gitconfig['system'] = { "http \"https://example.com\"" => ["sslVerify = false"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in omnibus configuration package like Fairy says.
Or you can use int a git bash command :

```
git config --global sslVerify false
```

This will disable the HTTPS verification of current repository